# R S4 roxygen2 documentation

Tags: r, documentation, r-s4, roxygen2

I'm using roxygen2 for documentation in S4 and for some reason the usage section is not showing up. I made a simple example to show my confusion:

```
#' Title
#'
#' @param x Temp
#'  
#' @return Nothing of interest.
#' 
#' @export 
#' @docType methods
#' @rdname A-methods
setGeneric("A", function(x, ...){
  cat("test\n")
  standardGeneric("A")
})

#' @rdname A-methods
#' @aliases A,ANY,ANY-method
setMethod("A", "ANY", function(x, ...){
  cat(class(x))
})

#END#
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IMHO that is a common problem. You could try to use the *s4* branch of roxygen. (For my small packages it works well.). To install the *s4* branch from [github](https://github.com/klutometis/roxygen):

```
library("devtools")
install_github("roxygen", "klutometis", ref="s4")
```

Comment: is roxygen2 unpopular for the development of large packages? seems like it can save some significant time and help with organization.

Comment: I can't really answer this question but many people use it for larger packages.