# R documenting S4 generic does not show usage

Tags: r, generics, documentation, r-s4, roxygen2

This question was already asked [in this stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18901589/r-s4-roxygen2-documentation) but the accepted answer (download the S4 branch from the author's repository) does not work for me and I think there might be a better way to achieve the same.

I have the following in my file `generics.R`:

```
#' @rdname myfunction-methods
#' @name myfunction <- without this, roxygen2 complaints about missing name
#' @export
methods::setGeneric("myfunction",
  function( arg1, arg2 ),
      arg3, arg4 {
        methods::standardGeneric("myfunction")
});
```

and then in my file `mymethods.R`:

```
#' Something
#'
#' A brief description
#'
#' @param all params... 
#' @return Something
#' @name myfunction <- without this, roxygen2 complaints on missing name
#' @include generics.R
#' @rdname myfunction-methods
#' @export
methods::setMethod( "myfunction",
  methods::signature( arg1 = "formula", arg2 = "data.frame" ),
  function( arg1, arg2, arg3, arg4 ) {

   ...whatever 
    }
)
```

With this, everything is fine except that the `usage`section is not showing up. Could you please correct what is wrong in my documentation? More precisely:

1. Is it correct to write the documentation before setMethod or is it preferably before setGeneric ?
2. Why do I need the `@name`in both files? Should it be different? Does it matter?
3. Do I need `@export` in both files?
4. Would `@alias` help at all?

Thank you very much in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't answer all you questions but maybe the following helps:

2. I think you may have a problem because `roxygen2` does not recognize `methods::setMethod` and `methods::setGeneric` when the file is parsed. You have to avoid the use of `::` - not generally just here - by importing the methods-package into your namespace via `#' @import methods`. Then you directly call `setMethod` and `setGeneric` without the reference to the package.

When this does not solve your problem you can always define the usage entry manually and still use roxygen2 like this: `#' @usage \S4method{myfunction}{formula,data.frame}(arg1, arg2)`.

Comment: You are right, the problem was caused by the `::`. I have removed them and added the `#' @import` and it works perfectly, and the `usage` section now appears correctly. Thanks!